# Can objects in space maintain a stable rotation spinning on two (or three) orthogonal axes simultaneously?

Tags: rotation, centrifugal-force

Could a space station spin on two (or three) orthogonal axes at once and maintain a stable rotation? If the station was a hollow sphere, would the centripetal force be equal everywhere on the interior shell?

Answer (score 2):

If any object were spinning around an axis, and an attempt is made to spin it around another, the additional torque would change the direction of the first axis of rotation.

Consequently, any rotating body will have only one axis of rotation at any given instant in time. Simultaneous axes of rotation in different directions for a rigid body is not possible.

Comment: Understood. But if that axis is constantly varying in orientation, what would be the practical effect on interior objects? I'm trying to understand if a spherical space station could somehow maintain a constant centripetal force along the entire shell, whether through inertia or continuously-applied force.

Comment: _what would be the practical effect on interior objects?_ How fast does it change orientation and with what speed and direction? How large is it? What is its tangential speed? If you can be more specific, that would help.  I also don’t understand what you mean by “shell” and “through inertia”.

Comment: By "shell" I mean the interior surface of a hollow sphere. By "through inertia" I meant an applied force that, once removed, would leave the sphere spinning with a non-stationary axis, if that's possible. The simplest case is to have the axis of the rotating object spinning around its own (orthogonal) axis. The axis of the rotating sphere should have a radial speed to match the rotation speed. A mile diameter is often used for examples of "artificial gravity" structures.